# Which methods are to be considered in method coverage

Tags: testing, code-coverage, white-box-testing

I have a confusion regarding the method coverage calculation.
consider the code below.

```
function A (n1)
{
if (n>1)
    C();
else
    print n1;
}
```

Now, My test case calls A() as
**A(1)**
It means function A will not call function C.
**Now, is method coverage 50% or 100%?**

Comment: It's 50%, since C is never called. Why would you think it would be 100%?

Comment: Because i read at one website that even if a single statement of a method is executed, it would be considered as covered. By that definition, it should be 100 % as function c is part of A

Comment: No, it only counts if execution enters the body of the method. Merely referring to the declaration from code that's never executed doesn't count.